# React Native - TypeScript in a JS file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So am I currently learning React Native by following app clones, such as Instagram, YouTube etc.
I have just started an AirBnb clone, but upon project creation, I am running into some issues with the initial build.

The first thing I noticed was in 'App.js', the template file for the app seems to be trying to use TypeScript inside a normal .js file. (I've never really used TS, so not sure if this is possible, or I'm just being stupid...) - see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUkBe.png)
for clarity. My understanding is the .js file is trying to import a type ('Node' as seen in the image) but surely it has to be a .ts or .tsx file? I haven't changed any file extensions, this is how it came in the template when I initialized the project.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Ah. It's not Typescript. If you look in the comments you can see `@flow strict-local`. I've never used it, but you can check it out here: https://flow.org/en/docs/

Comment: ah that makes sense - although, when I hover over the red underline, it says " 'import type' declarations can only be used in TypeScript files' ". Do you reckon this is something of concern?

Answer (score 2):

This is not typescript, it is flow.
You can check the documentation here, you will find the line which is imported:
https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/